# How can I print the entire database

Tags: java, mysql, executequery

I have a table called `ClientsTable` and a database called `myDb` .

How can I print with `System.out.prinln()` the entire database ? I just want to select all the rows and present all the fields to the screen .

Thanks

**EDIT:** what should I put instead of `rs.getString()` , here (since it doesn't compile):

```
    ResultSet rs = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CheckingAccountsTable");
    while (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getString());
```

Comment: how many tables are in your database?

Comment: @Blaine: 4 , but that doesn't work since I don't know what to put in the brackets of `rs` , here : `  ResultSet rs = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CheckingAccountsTable");
  while (rs.next())
   System.out.println(rs.getString());`

Comment: @Blaine:I've edited the post  , please take a look .

Comment: @Blaine he is using java not php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't know how many colums are in the table, try something like this :

```
    ResultSet rs = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CheckingAccountsTable");
    int columnCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
    while (rs.next()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: You may want to add _another_ for loop before the while loop to print the column names from rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_TABLE_NAME
```

Then you can loop through your result set and print it out.

Edit:

You aren't specifying what column you want to print out.

Example below:

```
System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
```

Second edit:

```
ResultSet rs = this.m_statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CheckingAccountsTable");
int colCount = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()){
    for(int i = 1; i < colCount + 1; i++){
       System.out.println(rs.getString(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I want all the columns , without "knowing" what they are , is that possible ?

Comment: I believe you will need to have nested loops then. I will edit my answer.

Comment: You can use getString with an integer instead of a string, getString(1) will return the 1st column for example

Comment: I've made my changes which are close to @mabroukb